# Não consigo fazer funcionar um gif animado em meu projeto WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Baixei um gif.animado nesse [link](http://www.gifsdahora.com.br/gifs_path/1753/zip/%22link%22). O problema que no link dou um duplo click e funciona. Arrasto para a minha aplicação e não funciona mais. A imagem aparece, mas parada e não em movimento. Quero colocar essa gif em lugar de uma progressbar.

Consegui em parte. Funcionou. Porém, quando eu inicio ela com Hidden e no código eu mando ela aparecer, é mostrada, mas sem movimento. Fica como uma imagem normal.

```
zipgif.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Seu link já está inválido. Outros gifs funcionam?

Comment: @RodrigoGuiotti, só testei esse. O que passa é que eu não sei trabalhar com gif animadas. Tenho que fazer algo no código ou no xaml?

Comment: dá pra fazer das duas formas, mas no xaml tem que baixar um pacote...

Comment: Achei aqui o nome: WpfAnimatedGif

Comment: @RodrigoGuiotti, cara, sabe onde eu encontro um tuto que me ensine a trampar com esse cara?

Comment: só em inglês... depois quando eu estiver com mais tempo, posso até traduzir mais coisas de lá... por isso que não montei uma resposta agora: https://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu estava buscando informações pois passava pelo mesmo problema, e no fim acabei encontrando a sua pergunta logo após eu encontrar uma resposta (rs).

Bom, para colocar um Gif em uma janela WPF, eu utilizei um `<MediaElement>`. No meu caso ficou algo assim:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" MediaEnded="mediaElement_MediaEnded" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Source="CaminhoAbsolutoPara/Gif.gif" Stretch="Fill" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>
```

E depois eu criei um evento pra que o Gif entrasse em um loop. No evento MediaEnded coloquei um codigo como esse:

```
private void mediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }
```

Bom, só uma pequena explicação para o código: o caminho Source para o Gif, deve ser absoluto. Por exemplo: C://...imagem.gif

No evento, o nome `mediaElement.Position`... e `mediaElement.Play` , é o nome que você deu ao seu MediaElement no trecho `x:Name="mediaElement"`

Já quanto as propriedades `HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200"` é algo pessoal seu.

Espero que eu tenha conseguido te ajudar. Abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Por padrão o WPF não oferece nenhum controle específico para a execução de arquivos de imagem Gif. Porém há dois modos simples de resolver esse problema:

1 • Anexar o Gif ao controle **MediaElement**. Sim, esse componente pode executar o Gif, porém ele não entrará em loop, você tem que fazer isso manualmente, e para isso você deve enraizar o evento **MediaEnded**, nele, resetar a propriedade **Position** e em seguida chamar o método **Play**.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Me" MediaEnded="MeMediaEnded" Source="meugif.gif" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" LoadedBehavior="Play"/>

private void MeMediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Reseta a posição.
    Me.Position = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

    //Executa novamente.
    Me.Play();
}
```

2 • Utilizar a biblioteca [**WpfAnimatedGif**](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/WpfAnimatedGif) que você pode baixar e referenciar no seu projeto através do NuGet

```
PM> Install-Package WpfAnimatedGif
```

Para utilizar basta adicionar o namespace ao seu arquivo Xaml e anexar as propriedades fornecidas pela biblioteca. Veja abaixo:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfGif.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="Images/meugif.gif" />
```